# log4net: Could not load type 'log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, log4net

I have a problem with the AdoNetAppender of log4net in my ASP.NET Core application (netcoreapp1.1).

If I want to use the AdoNetAppender, I get the following error:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender' from assembly 'log4net, Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a'.

Is there anybody who have the AdoNetAppender running under ASP.NET Core (netcoreapp1.1)? If not, is there a good alternative to log with log4net into a database? I also use Entity Framework Core.

Answer (score 7):

The `AdoNetAppender` isn't supported at present on .NET Core 1.0 / .NET Standard 1.3: https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/framework-support.html#Appenders

Comment: Exactly that I had feared. Is there a alternative to log into a database?

Comment: hi! Did you find a way to log into a database?

Answer (score 1):

For .Net Core you can use nuget.org/packages/MicroKnights.Log4NetAdoNetAppender . It has a bit differences in set up compare to AdoNetAppender, but is very straightforward too, to Find how to set it up here: github.com/microknights/Log4NetAdoNetAppender

Here an example that works for me

```
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="MicroKnights.Logging.AdoNetAppender, MicroKnights.Log4NetAdoNetAppender">
        <bufferSize value="1" />
        <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection,System.Data.SqlClient,Version=4.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <connectionStringName value="log4net" />
        <connectionStringFile value="appsettings.json" />
        <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ....." />
        <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@thread" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_level" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%level" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@logger" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@message" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%message" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@exception" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="2000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
    </parameter>
  </appender>
```

and in your appsettings.json

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"log4net": "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LogDB;User ID=user;Password=pass",
```

}